# Unable to Reflect Changes Made via WordPress Dashboard or REST API in the UI

Tags: wordpress, caching, wordpress-rest-api

I'm encountering an issue where changes made to posts either manually through the WordPress dashboard or via the WordPress REST API are not reflecting in the website's UI. *Despite successful modifications visible in the WordPress database (specifically wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables) as well as the WordPress dashboard*, the updates fail to appear on the website itself.

I've attempted several troubleshooting steps to address this issue:

1. Cleared all cache using W3 Total Cache plugin.
2. Applied "Purge All Caches".
3. Manually cleared browser cache.
4. Tried accessing the post URL with the /?nocache=1 query parameter.

Despite these efforts, the changes made either manually through the WordPress dashboard or via the REST API are still not reflecting in the website's UI.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try contacting your hosting providers to check if server-side caching is implemented on your website? If yes, then try clearing those caches. If still, the issue persists, then on your staging/testing environment I would suggest deactivating all plugins and switching to a default wp theme to check if the changes are reflecting.

Comment: Since I'm experiencing the issue in my local environment as well, contacting the hosting providers to check if server-side caching is enabled wouldn't be helpful, right?

Yes, I tried deactivating all the plugins, but it also didn't reflect the changes in the UI.